# Use multiple instances of DbContext when using AddDbContextPool

Tags: asp.net-core, concurrency, dbcontext, pool

I am using an implementation of GraphQL in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web server. It executes multiple resolver methods that requires `DbContext` through dependency injection in the same request. Previously, I used to configure `AddDbContext` with `contextLifetime` set to `ServiceLifetime.Transient` to avoid parallel operations on the same `DbContext`. Now, I would like to switch to `AddDbContextPool` to reuse instances of `DbContext` between requests and also **in the same request**. Is there a way to achieve this somehow?

Comment: There is no need to switch the lifetime of `DbContext` to transient. The default of scoped is perfectly fine. You won't run into any parallel ops issues unless you do it yourself in the same scope (within an action, for example), and transient wouldn't help you there, anyways, as it still would be the same instance for that scope.

Comment: HotChocolate does it in scope but it works perfectly with transient DI. Though I want to use pooling instead.

Answer (score 0):

On the original implementation by default AddDbContextPool uses AddScoped

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextPool<TContextService, TContextImplementation>(
      [NotNull] this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
      [NotNull] Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction,
      int poolSize = 128)
      where TContextService : class
      where TContextImplementation : DbContext, TContextService
    {
      Check.NotNull<IServiceCollection>(serviceCollection, nameof (serviceCollection));
      Check.NotNull<Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder>>(optionsAction, nameof (optionsAction));
      if (poolSize <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof (poolSize), CoreStrings.InvalidPoolSize);
      EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CheckContextConstructors<TContextImplementation>();
      EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddCoreServices<TContextImplementation>(serviceCollection, (Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder>) ((sp, ob) =>
      {
        optionsAction(sp, ob);
        CoreOptionsExtension extension = (ob.Options.FindExtension<CoreOptionsExtension>() ?? new CoreOptionsExtension()).WithMaxPoolSize(new int?(poolSize));
        ((IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure) ob).AddOrUpdateExtension<CoreOptionsExtension>(extension);
      }), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
      serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<DbContextPool<TContextImplementation>>((Func<IServiceProvider, DbContextPool<TContextImplementation>>) (sp => new DbContextPool<TContextImplementation>((DbContextOptions) sp.GetService<DbContextOptions<TContextImplementation>>())));

      //SEE THIS LINE HERE
      serviceCollection.AddScoped<DbContextPool<TContextImplementation>.Lease>();


      serviceCollection.AddScoped<TContextService>((Func<IServiceProvider, TContextService>) (sp => (TContextService) sp.GetService<DbContextPool<TContextImplementation>.Lease>().Context));
      return serviceCollection;
    }
```

Adding AddDbContextPool on your **ConfigureServices** should be enough

```
services.AddDbContextPool<YardCheckDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Also, it helps you to improve the average request per second, for more reference see this article where you can find a comparison with DbContextPool or without.
Hope this helps

[DbContext Pool](https://neelbhatt.com/2018/02/27/use-dbcontextpooling-to-improve-the-performance-net-core-2-1-feature/)